# Is a ROMs data (/data) from Nougat compatible with MM?

Tags: updates, custom-roms, data-recovery

I have a Nexus 6p with Resurrection Remix, Android 7.1.1. I want to move back to Marshmallow (still RR) for Xposed. I plan to just dirty flash the old RR 6.0.1 .zip file. Will this result in any problems with my data? Like my installed apps, data for those apps...?

Thanks in advance. If you need more information just ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From one of my earlier answers:

> Older version of an app might not recognize the data created by the newer version of the same app. Although user apps are rarely affected, crucial system apps might be, and on error might constantly throw "*** has stopped" dialogs that effectively prevents you from using the phone.

Also, some newer ROMs have alerts in their `updater-script` that detect different `/data` formats and, if detected, throw error about it, and will not proceed unless you perform a wipe.

Comment: I just took a NAndroid backup of a few key partitions, and moved the backup to a flash drive. Then I wiped everything. When I have time I am going to transfer it back to internal storage and restore all my apps and data with Titanium.

Answer (score 0):

You can also backup all your apps data using TitaniumBackup, do the downgrade and then restore previously backed up apps data.